# Display Node Local Tasks Menu on View

Tags: 8, views, nodes

I have a view that shows registrations for an Event (Content Type).
This tab is shown in the /node/{node}/edit:

[image: menuregistrations]

This registrations tab refers to the view, which I have inserted in the routing.yml:

```
events.registrations:
  path: '/node/{node}/registrations'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'registrations.page_1'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\events\Access\EventsRegistrationsAccess::checkAccess'
    node: \d+
  options:
    parameters:
      node:
        type: entity:node
```

And inserted additionally, events.links.task.yml:

```
entity.node.registrations:
  route_name: events.registrations
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: 'Registrations'
  weight: 20
```

Then the view displays the following:

[image: menu-missing]

Question: How can I show the menu navigation for the node (same as the first image) on the route '/node/78/registrations' which only shows the view without navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was too complicated to attach a navigation menu on a view, instead I used controller that loads a block display from the view programmatically and the navigation was automatically attached.